# Enterprise Library Logging : Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""

Tags: logging, configuration, enterprise-library

I'm trying to write a log without having a configuration file by using Fluent API.

this is my code:

```
 var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
                builder.ConfigureData()
                .ForDatabaseNamed("Logging")
                .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
                .WithConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                .AsDefault();

 var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
 builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);

 var logger = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();

 logger.Write("Test", "General");
```

when I run this it just says that

> Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type LogWriter, key ""

what did I do wrong in configuration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things missing:

1. You forgot to update the container with the configuration using the `EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer` method
2. You are configuring data access but are trying to use the logging block

Here's how you create the container with the configuration information:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
                builder.ConfigureData()
                .ForDatabaseNamed("Logging")
                .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
                .WithConnectionString(ConnectionString)
                .AsDefault();

 var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
 builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);

 EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

To configure logging using the Fluent API see [Using the Fluent Configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_logging).

The example from that article is:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureLogging()
       .WithOptions
         .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
       .LogToCategoryNamed("Security")
         .SendTo.FlatFile("Security Log File")
           .FormatWith(new FormatterBuilder()
             .TextFormatterNamed("Text Formatter")
               .UsingTemplate("Timestamp: {timestamp}...{newline})}"))
             .ToFile("security.log")
         .SendTo.EventLog("Formatted EventLog TraceListener")
            .FormatWithSharedFormatter("Text Formatter")
              .ToLog("Application")
       .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
         .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
         .SendTo.SharedListenerNamed("Formatted EventLog TraceListener");

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```

If you wish to configure both the logging block to write to a database using the data access block you can also do it using the fluent interface:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureData()
    .ForDatabaseNamed("Logging")
        .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
        .WithConnectionString(@"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Database=Logging")
    .AsDefault();

builder.ConfigureLogging()
        .WithOptions
            .DoNotRevertImpersonation()
        .LogToCategoryNamed("General")
            .WithOptions.SetAsDefaultCategory()
            .SendTo.Database("Database Trace Listener")
            .WithAddCategoryStoredProcedure("AddCategory")
            .UseDatabase("Logging")
            .Filter(System.Diagnostics.SourceLevels.All)
            .WithWriteLogStoredProcedure("WriteLog");


var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current
    = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);

var logger = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
logger.Write(logEntry);
Logger.Write("Test", "General");
```

Comment: yes thank you very much ... you made good notes .. but the problem is I cannot undrestand the complexity of configuring Logging block. this sample code from MSDN is just showing how to write to Event Log not Database. I could not find any source that shows how to configure Logging with fluent API

Comment: I second that, you are awesome.

Comment: Awesome post. Thanks. But I think it is also have the same problem I am having. When the `logger` will be unloaded?